# Is "at the expensive of" a correct expression?

Tags: word-usage

> The European commissioner for competition, Margrethe Vestager, said this morning that the EU is willing to investigate the settlement, telling BBC Radio 4 that these sorts of "sweetheart deals" can amount to "illegal state aid," and that they benefit established companies **at the expensive of** newer businesses. [theverge.com](http://www.theverge.com/2016/1/28/10858210/google-sweetheart-uk-tax-deal-criticism)

I came across the expression "at the expensive of" while reading an English newspaper today and am having a hard time understanding its grammar since "expensive" is an adjective. I googled that expression and even Google says "Did you mean: **at the expense of**." It's surprising still there are more than 50,000 results with the expression "at the expensive of."

So, my question is,

1. Is "at the expensive of" a correct expression?
2. If it is, how can it be grammatically explained?

Comment: "*at the expense of*" is a commonly used idiom. I've not come across "*at the expensive of*".

Comment: It doesn't look correct.  This might have been an editing mistake by theverge.  If someone absent-mindedly writes "expensive" when they meant "expense", a spell-checker won't catch it.  Alternately, the writer might have made a typo, and a spell-checker suggested "expensive" as the best fix, and the editor accepted it without seeing if it was really correct.

Comment: Those are very valid assumption @stangdon, your deductive skills are quite commendable.

Comment: I had to read the sentence three times before I realized it said "expensive" and not "expense"! Sometimes your mind sees what it wants. Pretty sure this is a typo, possibly caused by an auto-spell check.

Comment: Somebody has **transcribed the passage incorrectly**, if you look at the original it's: "they benefit established companies at the **expense** of newer businesses". Good to know not everyone just cuts and pastes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a small mistake on the side of Verge. A very commonly used idiom is:

> **at the expense of (someone or something)**

Which means :

1. in a way that harms (something or someone).
2. paid by someone else (in terms of cash).
3. with the loss of something.

> - The hotel flourished **at the expense of** small eateries beside it.
> - She acquired the land **at the expense of** her good name in the society.
> - He thinks that the the new tax laws will benefit the rich **at the expense of** the poor.
> - He booked the air tickets **at the expense of** the company.